# Convert 2 cascaded select in a menu (in desktop mode) and show regular select in mobile mode

Tags: jquery

Today i have found a interesting solution ( http://jsfiddle.net/mBUgc/21/ ) that converts a classic select into a list of buttons and i would like to know if this can be converted into a regular menu.

This menu, if can be done, must show like this in desktop mode and if in tablet/phone mode, show the regular select. This part can be done by using 
some code like `if ($(window).width() > 768) {show the converted select} else {  show regular select};`

The structure is:

```
<div class="category-container">
  <p>Chose category</p>
  <select id="select_1" name="text">
    <option>Category 1</option>
    <option>Category 2</option>
    <option>Category 3</option>
    <option>Category 4</option>
    <option>Category 5</option>
    <option>Category 6</option>
    <option>Category 7</option>
    <option>Category 8</option>
    <option>Category 9</option>
    <option>Category 10</option>
    <option>Category 11</option>
    <option>Category 12</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When you select one option from first select, second select should appears and shows the subcategories for the category we selected.

```
<div class="subcategory-container">
  <p>Chose subcategory</p>
  <select id="select_2" name="text">
    <option>Subcategory 1</option>
    <option>Subcategory 2</option>
    <option>Subcategory 3</option>
    <option>Subcategory 4</option>
    <option>Subcategory 5</option>
    <option>Subcategory 6</option>
    <option>Subcategory 7</option>
    <option>Subcategory 8</option>
    <option>Subcategory 9</option>
    <option>Subcategory 10</option>
    <option>Subcategory 11</option>
    <option>Subcategory 12</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/fjs2jyr1/7/) so you can check the functionality so far.

This must work in IE8 as well if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the credit goes to Vijayakrishnan Krishnan

```js
if ($(window).width() > 768) {


  var selectName = $('select').attr('name');

  // add a hidden elements with the same names as the selects
  $('select').each(function() {
    var hidden = $('<input type="hidden" name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '">');
    hidden.val($(this).val());
    hidden.insertAfter($(this));
  });

  $("select[name=category] option").unwrap().each(function() {
    var btn = $('<div class="category" data-category-id="' + $(this).data('category-id') + '">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
    //if ($(this).is(':checked')) btn.addClass('on');
    $(this).replaceWith(btn);
  });

  $('select[name=subcategory]').each(function() {
    var categoryID = $(this).data('category-id');
    $(this).find('option').unwrap().each(function() {
      var btn = $('<div class="subcategory" data-belongs-to="' + categoryID + '">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
      //if ($(this).is(':checked')) btn.addClass('on');
      $(this).replaceWith(btn);
    });
  });

  // category click handler
  $(document).on('click', '.category, .subcategory', function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('input[name="' + selectName + '"]').val($(this).text());

    // check if clicked element is a category, if so show appropriate subcategories
    if ($(this).is('.category')) {

      // hide everything first
      $('div.subcategory-container').addClass('hidden');
      $('.subcategory').hide();

      // check if there are any subcategories, if so show them
      if ($('.subcategory[data-belongs-to=' + $(this).data('category-id') + ']').length) {
        $('div.subcategory-container').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.subcategory[data-belongs-to=' + $(this).data('category-id') + ']').show();
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  $("select[name=category]").change(function() {
    $('div.subcategory-container').addClass('hidden');
    $('select[name=subcategory]').hide();
    var cat = $(this).find('option:checked').data('category-id');
    if ($('select[name=subcategory][data-category-id=' + cat + ']').length) {
      $('div.subcategory-container').removeClass('hidden');
      $('select[name=subcategory][data-category-id=' + cat + ']').show();
    }
  });
};
```

```css
div.category-container,
div.subcategory-container {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
div.category,
div.subcategory {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
div.category.on,
div.subcategory.on {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
}
p {
  width: 100%
}
div.subcategory-container.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category-container">
  <p>Chose category</p>
  <select id="select_1" name="category" data-level="1">
    <option data-category-id="1">Category 1</option>
    <option data-category-id="2">Category 2</option>
    <option data-category-id="3">Category 3</option>
    <option data-category-id="4">Category 4</option>
    <option data-category-id="5">Category 5</option>
    <option data-category-id="6">Category 6</option>
    <option data-category-id="7">Category 7</option>
    <option data-category-id="8">Category 8</option>
    <option data-category-id="9">Category 9</option>
    <option data-category-id="10">Category 10</option>
    <option data-category-id="11">Category 11</option>
    <option data-category-id="12">Category 12</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="subcategory-container hidden">
  <p>Chose subcategory</p>
  <select id="select_2" name="subcategory" data-category-id="4">
    <option>Subcategory 1</option>
    <option>Subcategory 2</option>
    <option>Subcategory 3</option>
    <option>Subcategory 4</option>
    <option>Subcategory 5</option>
    <option>Subcategory 6</option>
    <option>Subcategory 7</option>
    <option>Subcategory 8</option>
    <option>Subcategory 9</option>
    <option>Subcategory 10</option>
    <option>Subcategory 11</option>
    <option>Subcategory 12</option>
  </select>
</div>

<p>When we select a option like Category 4, show it's subcategories in another select menu like Chose subcategory. <i>Note: Only category 4 currently has any subcategories in it</i>
</p>
```